# SDL2 Build fails [Eclipse]

Tags: c, eclipse, sdl-2

i am trying to setup SDL2 with eclipse(linux), but eclipse only throw errors "undefined reference". I found on google that i need to add this flag "-lSDL2" to the linker. So i go to `Project Settings -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> GCC Linker -> Miscellaneous` and added it there to the Linker flags. But it doesn't work, eclipse throw this error:

```
Building target: test_c
Invoking: GCC C Linker
gcc -lSDL2 -o "test_c"  ./main.o   
./main.o: In function `main':
/home/nimmi/Documents/workspace/test_c/Debug/../main.c:7: undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
makefile:29: recipe for target 'test_c' failed
/home/nimmi/Documents/workspace/test_c/Debug/../main.c:11: undefined reference to `SDL_CreateWindow'
/home/nimmi/Documents/workspace/test_c/Debug/../main.c:20: undefined reference to `SDL_UpdateWindowSurface'
/home/nimmi/Documents/workspace/test_c/Debug/../main.c:21: undefined reference to `SDL_Delay'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [test_c] Error 1

12:17:09 Build Finished (took 172ms)
```

Comment: `gcc -lSDL2 -o "test_c"  ./main.o` or `gcc -o "test_c"  ./main.o -lSDL2`???

Comment: @SouravGhosh it works for me if i type "gcc main.c -lSDL2" in the terminal. So i think "gcc -o 'test_c' ./main.o -lSDL2" is the right one.